# how to modify number of files using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Guys i have this sample code from a book that shows how to modify contents in number of files using regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    chomp(my $date = `date`);
    $^I = ".bak";
    while (<>) {
      s/^Author:.*/Author: Randal L. Schwartz/;
      s/^Phone:.*\n//;
      s/^Date:.*/Date: $date/;
      print;
    }
```

From the look of it, i know something is missing - which is the filename. But the book insists. So when i try it myself, it only accepts input from the keyboard which is what i expected. So i have a modified code which opens a file instead but it wont create a backup anymore:

which is handled by this line

```
$^I = ".out";



#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (MYFILE,'fewlines');
$^I = ".out";

while (<MYFILE>) {
    s/fred/larry/ig;
    print;
}
```

This line also do the same, but in the command prompt. I want to write a program itself not in the command prompt

```
perl -p -i.out -w -e 's/fred/larry/ig' filename
```

How to convert that line in a program itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<>`, short for `<ARGV>`, reads the file named in `@ARGV` if any, and STDIN otherwise.

```
perl -p -i.out -w -e 's/fred/larry/ig' filename
```

does

```
@ARGV = 'filename';
$^I = '.out'
$^W = 1;
LINE: while (<>) {
   s/fred/larry/ig
} continue {
   die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Comment: hey ikegami (are you a Perl God? :D), few more questions. So i entered in the command prompt this one -----> perl myprogram < filename. It creates filename~.out, but neither one of the filename's contents are modified and what the heck is the ~ doing there?. how is that? *note i used my code but i omitted the STDIN letting the '<' handle the input. Also is \@ARGV specific to <> only? cause ive come across with this @ARGV a lot of times and i dont understand what it is

Comment: Hey @ikegami where are you

Comment: Hm, -MO=Deparse doesn't mention "die" in continue block.

Comment: @mpapec, Was added three (almost four) versions ago in 5.12.0.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, I can't answer questions about `myprogram` when I don't know what it is, though part of the answer is that `perl myprogram < filename` doesn't pass any args to Perl other than `myprogram`.

Comment: myprogram is the above code ikegami, i passed the filename to it

Comment: @ikegami, yes and I'm with 5.10 (it seems that debian/centos are stuck with it)

Comment: @mpapec, So what? How is your the version you're using in any way relevant?

Comment: @ikegami, I was making a simple comment about versions. What made you think that I assume any relevance to it?

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, No, you didn't. I didn't ask "did you pass a file name?". I didn't ask question at all. I informed you that "`perl myprogram < filename`" doesn't pass any args to Perl other than `myprogram`.

Comment: @ikegami, I'm sorry if you think in such way.

Comment: @mpapec, Actually, it's SO policy. If you want to chat, maybe you can find someone interested in the [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) part of the site. Or maybe PerlMonks's Meditations section, where they let you air your mind, is more to your liking.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, Missed one of your questions: `@ARGV` receives the command-line args passed to your script. It's to your script as `@_` is to subs.